# Symfony2.3, Relational entity in 1 form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I am trying to save entities of 2 classes in 1 form I have read  [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) article about it. My code is :

```
class MeetingType extends AbstractType
  {
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('meetingDay', 'text', array('label' => 'Dzień zbiórki'))
        ->add('meetingTime', 'text', array('label' => 'Godzina zbiórki'))
        ->add('congregation', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'ViszmanCongregationBundle:Congregation',
                'property' => 'name', 'label' => 'Zbór'
        ));
  }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Viszman\CongregationBundle\Entity\Meeting'
    ));
  }

/**
 * @return string
 */
  public function getName()
  {
      return 'viszman_congregationbundle_meeting';
  }
}
```

And another TYPE:

```
class CongregationType extends AbstractType
  {
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $plDays = array('day1', 'day1', 'day1', 'day1', 'day1', 'day1', 'day1');
    $builder
        ->add('name',           'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
        ->add('meetingDay',     'choice', array('label' => 'meeting day', 'choices' => $plDays))
        ->add('meetings','collection', array('type' => new MeetingType(), 'allow_add' => true))
    ;
  }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Viszman\CongregationBundle\Entity\Congregation'
    ));
  }

/**
 * @return string
 */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'viszman_congregationbundle_congregation';
  }
}
```

And when I try do render this form I only get `CongregationType` and no `MeetingType` form. part of code responsible for rendering form is:

```
<h1>Congregation creation</h1>

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
  <h3>Meetings</h3>
  <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.meetings.vars.prototype)|e }}">
{{ form_widget(form.meetings) }}
</ul>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: For starters, form_widget(form) will render the rest of all the form widgets including form.meetings.  Secondly, in the $congregation object you are passing to the CongregationFormType, are there any meeting objects?  If you don't pass any then none will be rendered.

Comment: from the article that i readed in symfony site about embedded forms, i understand that it is to create new objects

Comment: The entity field-type is for selection of an existing entity.

Comment: Best to work your way through the example.  Form collections can be a bit confusing.  But no, they themselves don't create entities.  Near the end of the article they talk a bit about using javascript to add new entities.  But that is a bit different.  Not to worry.  Once you understand what is happening then collections can be quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the entity form field is used to reference an existing entity, not to create a new one.

This is not what you need, what you need is embedded forms, take a look at [the symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms).